# How to get Timeformat of Pandas Time-Index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format, time-format

Assume I have a Dataframe:

```
>>>df1
                          Col1       Col1
               Time
2013-05-08 00:00:00    1.25468    1.25468
2013-05-09 00:00:00    1.24833    1.25468
2013-05-10 00:00:00    1.24458    1.25468
2013-05-13 00:00:00    1.23918    1.25468
2013-05-14 00:00:00    1.23527    1.25468
```

Question:

How can I get the Timeformat of the Timeindex, so that i can apply it on another timeframe with pd.to_datetime()?

like this:

```
>>> timeformat = get_timeformat(df1)
>>> df2
                              Col1       Col1
                   Time
2013-05-08 00:00:00:000    10.25468    1.25468
2013-05-09 00:00:00:000    19.24833    1.25468
2013-05-10 00:00:00:000    18.24458    1.25468
2013-05-13 00:00:00:000    14.23918    1.25468
2013-05-14 00:00:00:000    13.23527    1.25468

>>> timeCol_name = "Time"
>>> df2[timeCol_name ] = pd.to_datetime(df2[timeCol_name ], 
                                          format = timeformat) # <--- this is what i need

                           Col1       Col1
               Time
2013-05-08 00:00:00    10.25468    1.25468
2013-05-09 00:00:00    19.24833    1.25468
2013-05-10 00:00:00    18.24458    1.25468
2013-05-13 00:00:00    14.23918    1.25468
2013-05-14 00:00:00    13.23527    1.25468
```

The ones above are just examples. for my purpose the datetimeformat could by any format (therefore the function needs to be dynamic)

Comment: `Timeindex` does not have a `Timeformat` property. `format` is to ditate just how you want to **render/view** the values stored in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you set the exact same format in both the dataframes:

```
t_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.strftime(t_format)
```

Do the same on the other one:

```
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time']).dt.strftime(t_format)
```

**Output:**

```
                  Time     col1     col2
0  2013-05-08 00:00:00  1.25468  1.25468
1  2013-05-09 00:00:00  1.24833  1.25468
2  2013-05-10 00:00:00  1.24458  1.25468
3  2013-05-13 00:00:00  1.23918  1.25468
4  2013-05-14 00:00:00  1.23527  1.25468
```

Comment: because the timeformat in my program isnt always the same when entered. Finding this specific timeformat is exactly what is needed.